# Input mask for ExtJs 6 textfield

Tags: mask, extjs6.2

I have a textfield mask in ExtJs 4. It can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/loiane/909119)

Can anyone point me in the direction of a textmask example in ExtJs6.

Comment: Do you want to use same [mask](https://gist.github.com/loiane/909119) in [ExtJs 6.2](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/index.html) ?

Comment: It can be used directly in ExtJs 6 as it is pure javascript.At least all the functionalities are . I don't to deal with html elements here. It should be in ExtJs.

Comment: I didn't get you about `I don't to deal with html elements here`  please explain

Comment: with the latest extjs (6.5.2) you have http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.field.InputMask.html for both modern and classic toolkits

Comment: @MarcoC. There is no Ext.field.InputMask in ExtJs 6.2.0

Comment: Yes but the upgrade from 6.2 to 6.5 should not be too difficult...

Comment: I am not the decision maker . And aslo there is no GPL for 6.5.So it is not of any use.

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote a simple masked textfield for **ExtJS 6.2**. All you need to do is to create a file called `MaskedField.js` and paste the following code:

```
Ext.define('Ext.field.MaskedField', {
    extend: Ext.field.Text,
    alias: 'widget.maskedfield',
    config: {
        label: '',
        mask: null,
        defaultDateFormat: 'm/d/Y'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        const me = this;

        me.callParent();

        if (Ext.String.trim(me.config.mask) != "") me.setMaxLength(me.config.mask.length);
    },

    listeners: {
        change: function(textfield, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
            if (newValue instanceof Date) newValue = Ext.Date.format(newValue, textfield.config.defaultDateFormat);
            if (isFinite(newValue)) newValue = String(newValue);
            if (oldValue && newValue.length < oldValue.length) return; // Backspace pressed

            let mask = textfield.config.mask;
            if (!mask) return; // Avoid auto-bind error
            let mf = mask.split('');
            let vf = newValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').split(''); // Mask for numbers only
            let index = 0;
            mf.map((m, i) => {
                if (m === '#') {
                    mf[i] = vf[index++];
                }
            });

            let value = '';
            for (m of mf) {
                if (m) {
                    value += m;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            textfield.suspendEvent('change');
            textfield.setValue(value);
            textfield.resumeEvent('change');
        }
      }
});
```

This component **does not validates** any kind of data. It only gives user the ability to type with automatic masking.

**You can't use numbers as part of the mask** (it only accepts special characters, spaces and letters). The mask `'## 9###'` will fail, but `'## A###'` will work fine!

You can use this component as follows:

```
{
  xtype: 'maskedfield',
  name: 'birthday',
  label: 'Your birthday',
  mask: '##/##/####',
  defaultDateFormat: 'd/m/Y' // Same format as Ext.Date
},
{
  xtype: 'maskedfield',
  name: 'phone',
  label: 'Your cellphone',
  mask: '(##) #####-####'
},
{
  xtype: 'maskedfield',
  name: 'postalcode',
  label: 'Postal code',
  mask: '#####-###'
}
```

You must declare the mask using '#'.

Comment: I am working to put some validation on this component. I will update my answer as soon as I get it working!